# default passwords for mythbuntu

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

I have downloaded and installed mythbuntu.
Very clean process.

I now need to install shepherd for Australian EPG.
When I
  wget 'http://www.whuffy.com/shepherd/shepherd'
it loads the file to my user directory but it should be in mythtv directory.

When I try
  su mythtv
I do not have the correct password for mythtv.
I also do not know the password for running as root.

I have tried passwords mythtv and mythbuntu without success.

Can you please advise what the default root and mythtv passwords are.

Regards
Glen

Comment: To anyone who sees this in the close queue: This is not off-topic. Mythbuntu is [an official derivative](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/derivatives) so we [totally support it](http://askubuntu.com/faq).

Answer (score 2):

If the mythtv user is created as a system user, it won't have a password set and might be configured so you cannot log in as it.

Typically, you can log in as another user using `sudo`. If your account was the one created as the administrator when you installed Mythtbuntu, you will already be set up to use `sudo`. You can then try:

```
sudo -i -u mythtv
```

However, if the mythtv user does not have a shell configured, then you still might not be able to log in as that user. You can try setting a shell for the mythtv user:

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash mythtv
```

Or rather than trying to log in as that user, simply run individual commands as that user using `sudo`:

```
sudo -u mythtv "<command_to_run>"
```

In a similar vein, can also log in as root using `sudo -i -u root`, or open a new shell as root by running `sudo bash`.

Lastly, if you really want to, you can use `sudo` to set a password for the mythtv user:

```
sudo passwd mythtv
```